# Problema con Paginate Flask y current_user

Tags: flask

tengo un problema con el paginate de Flask que no me filtra los clientes del usuario que inició sesión.
Está todo pero me falta el .items pero nose como ni donde agregarlo.
Adjunto código de ***vista***:

```
@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={"page": 1}) 
@views.route('/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home(page):
    client = Client.query.paginate(page=page,per_page=3,error_out=False)  
    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, client=client)
```

Adjunto código de ***template***:

```
{% for client in user.clients %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ client.id}}</th>
        <td>{{ client.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ client.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ client.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{ client.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="/update/{{client.id}}" class="btn btn-warning active" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editModal{{client.id}}"  aria-pressed="true">Edit</a>
          <a href="/delete/{{client.id}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete ?')">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

***Lo que es la navegación está hecha con boostrap 5 y está funcionando, lo único es que no me filtra los clientes del usuario que inició la sesión***

De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

en la función de python haces este query que obtiene todos los clientes de tu bd y luego lo pasas a la página

`client = Client.query.paginate(page=page,per_page=3,error_out=False)`

puedes probar sólo los de la sesión actual y asumiendo que tienes la columna user_id en Client

```
clients = Client.query.paginate(user_id=current_user.id, page=page,per_page=3,error_out=False)

return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, clients=clients)

{% for client in clients %}
{% endfor %}
```